# Probability of sum of independent variables less than amount

Tags: probability

I have an ungraded homework assignment that has had me stumped for the better part of an hour. I have a really ugly solution but honestly I'm just not sure where to start. This is what I have so far:

$$
1 - \sum_{i=0}^{min(n_1,{c \over r_1})}\Bigg({n_1 \choose i}p_1^i(1-p_1)^{n_1-i}\sum_{j=0}^{min(n_2,{{c - ir_1} \over r_2})}{n_2 \choose j}p_2^j(1-p_2)^{n_2-j}\Bigg)
$$

The problem is:

> A cellular phone system services a population of n1 voice users and n2
>   data users. We estimate that at given time, each user will need to be
>   connected to the system with probability p1 for voice users and p2 for
>   data users, independent of other users. The data rate for a voice user
>   is r1 bit/sec, and for a data user is r2 bit/sec. The system has a
>   capacity of c bit/sec. Use the above notations (n1, n2, p1, p2, r1,
>   r2, c) to express the probability that more users want to use the
>   system than the system can accommodate. (Hint: supplementary notations
>   may be needed, e.g. use i to denote the number of voice users who want
>   to connect at the moment, and j denote the number of data users who
>   want to connect at the moment, where 0 ≤ i ≤ n1 and 0 ≤ j ≤ n2).